# tkinter: How do I make these boxes fit to the left and be in straight line

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, user-experience

As you can see my boxes are not in straight line. I would like to make them be in straight line and more to the left.
my code:

```
has_lower_box = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="lower chars", variable=has_lower_value)
has_lower_box.grid(row=0, column=1)
has_upper_box = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="upper chars", variable=has_upper_value)
has_upper_box.grid(row=1, column=1)
has_upper_box = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="special chars", variable=has_special_value)
has_upper_box.grid(row=2, column=1)
```

[checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wVWb.png)

Comment: no, I can't view your program because you haven't provided a [mre]

Comment: research the `sticky` attribute of the `grid` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to line them up using the `sticky=` [Tkinter Grid Geometry Manager](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111175154id_/http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) option. I set it to `sticky=W` for West, which of course means the left side.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import *

root = tk.Tk()

has_lower_value = tk.BooleanVar()
has_upper_value = tk.BooleanVar()
has_special_value = tk.BooleanVar()

has_lower_box = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="lower chars", variable=has_lower_value)
has_lower_box.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
has_upper_box = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="upper chars", variable=has_upper_value)
has_upper_box.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
has_upper_box = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="special chars", variable=has_special_value)
has_upper_box.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)

root.mainloop()
```

Here's an enlarged screenshot showing the results:

[image: enlarged screenshot]

Comment: Thank you very much !